# How can I determine if one set of vectors has the same span as another set using ONLY the Elimination Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Linear Algebra course textbook, we are asked to determine which subsets have the same span as the original set using only the Elimination Theorem, as can be seen in the link to the screenshot. (BTW, I've looked up and down the Internet for more lessons on using the Elimination Theorem for multiple types of problems, but I have not found anything yet, not even anything explicitly labeled "Elimination Theorem", which makes me think it could go by a different term.) I am aware that if a set has vectors that are linearly dependent, you can "eliminate" those vectors until you get down to a certain set of vectors which can no longer be eliminated, and thus, you've arrived at a set of vectors which are linearly INDEPENDENT. I've worked on problems that give us a set of vectors with specific vector components with no issue at all. However, in this problem, they do not provide specific vector components, and my issue is that I don't know how to approach this problem. According to the textbook, the answer is: a, b, and d. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Elimination Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWHg.jpg)

[Problem 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4X6M.jpg)
[image]

Comment: You never say what the "elimination theorem" is, but likely it means you can test if one vector is in the span of the others, and eliminate it if so.  So likely you just sequentially eliminate vectors, in any order, to get down to the smaller set.

Comment: I just posted a link to the screenshot of the Elimination Theorem according to the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get $a,b$ and $d$.

For instance  $a$ does because $v_3$ can be eliminated,  as it is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

$b$ does because we can eliminate one of $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$...  and one of $v_4$ and $v_5$.

Comment: How were you able to eliminate v3? That's the big issue for me; I don't know how to eliminate certain vectors when I am not given specific vector components.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it looks like c is not correct, since $S_3$ can be further reduced to the span of $v_1$ and $v_5$.

Comment: @Michael. You're right.   My mistake.

Comment: @duck_duck_goose. Whenever $n$ vectors are linearly dependent, you can take [any] one out without changing the span.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is how do you decide which vectors you can eliminate by only using those two linear combinations provided in the problem. I guess a better question would be: what do those two given linear combinations represent?

Comment: Why isn’t $b$ correct? It eliminates $v_2$ and $v_5$, so the reason you give doesn’t even apply.

Comment: @Michael can I ask you how you arrived at your answer?

Comment: b is correct.  I blew it again...

Comment: @duck_duck_goose : Chris explains $a$ and $b$ already, so the same technique is used for $d$.  For $a$, you can directly apply elimination theorem to remove $v_3$ from the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$, because we know $v_3 = \frac{1}{2}(8v_2 - 3v_1)$. So even if we remove $v_3$,  we can always reconstruct $v_3$ again from $v_1$ and $v_2$, which is why Chris says $v_3$ "is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$."  Another aspect of the problem is to show specific examples for $c$ and $e$.  That is, _sometimes_ $c$ and $e$ also have the same span (as wehn all vectors are 0), but not always.

Comment: @Michael okay, I get it.